# Unity - OnTriggerExit is not getting invoked when character control passes through

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine

Developing simple game prototype. I have a `capusle` as a player and `character controller` is attached to it. when it goes through the game object which has `isTrigger` checked, `OnTriggerExit(Collider other)` is not getting invoked. The script for OnTriggerExit is attached to the gameobject which is the child to a platform.

Any obvious reason why the the OnTriggerExit is not getting invoked? Attached the inspector screen shots of the player and isTrigger gameobject.

[image: isTrigger]

[image: player]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The box collider from CubeEnd is disabled.